# How can I upload the first name, last name, job and profile picture of the user?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Please Help me**
I want to know how to upload the first name, last name, job, date of birth and a picture of the user in **Flutter** [Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)

this is my signup

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newlivenullsaf/pages/login.dart';

class Signup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Signup> createState() => _SignupState();
}

class _SignupState extends State<Signup> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var email = '';
  var password = '';
  var confirmPassword = '';
  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    confirmPasswordController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  bool isLoading = false;
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();
  registeration() async {
    if (password == confirmPassword) {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
        print(UserCredential);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            content: Text(
              'Registerd Successfully. Please Sign In ',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const LoginPage(),
          ),
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        if (error.code == 'week-password') {
          print('Password is too week');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              content: Text(
                'Password is too week ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.amberAccent),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (error.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          print('Account is already exists');
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              content: Text(
                'Account is already exists ',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.amberAccent),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    } else {
      print('Password and Confirm Password does not match ');
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          content: Text(
            'Password and Confirm Password does not match ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.amberAccent),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: Container(
                height: size.height / 20,
                width: size.height / 20,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            )
          : Form(
              key: _formkey,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      child: Image.asset('images/signup.png'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Name:',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                          ),
                          controller: nameController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isNotEmpty) {
                              return 'Please Enter Your Name';
                            }
                            if (value.length > 4) {
                              return (' Name(Max. 4 Character)');
                            }

                            return null;
                          }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                          autofocus: false,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Last Name:',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                          ),
                          controller: nameController,
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isNotEmpty) {
                              return 'Please Enter Your Last Name';
                            }
                            if (value.length > 4) {
                              return ('Last Name(Max. 4 Character)');
                            }

                            return null;
                          }),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Email:',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          errorStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                        ),
                        controller: emailController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Please Enter Email';
                          } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
                            return 'Please Enter Valid Email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: ' Password',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          errorStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                        ),
                        controller: passwordController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null ||
                              value.isEmpty ||
                              value.length < 6 ||
                              value.length > 14) {
                            return 'Please Enter Password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        autofocus: false,
                        obscureText: true,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Confirm Password',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          errorStyle:
                              TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                        ),
                        controller: confirmPasswordController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value == null ||
                              value.isEmpty ||
                              value.length < 6 ||
                              value.length > 14) {
                            return 'Please Confirm Password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                setState(() {
                                  email = emailController.text;
                                  password = passwordController.text;
                                  confirmPassword =
                                      confirmPasswordController.text;
                                });
                                registeration();
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text(
                              'Signup ',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text('Already Have An Account ?'),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                PageRouteBuilder(
                                  pageBuilder:
                                      (context, animation1, animation2) =>
                                          const LoginPage(),
                                  transitionDuration:
                                      const Duration(seconds: 0),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: const Text('Login'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my main

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newlivenullsaf/pages/login.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('something wrong');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter email & password',
          theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
          home: const LoginPage(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

this is my login

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:newlivenullsaf/pages/forget_password.dart';
import 'package:newlivenullsaf/pages/signup.dart';
import 'package:newlivenullsaf/pages/user_main.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var email = "";
  var password = "";
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  userLogin() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const UserMain()));
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      if (error.code == ' user-not-found') {
        print('No user found for that email ');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            content: Text(
              'No user found for that email',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else if (error.code == 'wrong-password') {
        print('wrong password provided by the user');
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            content: Text(
              'wrong password provided by the user',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40.0, horizontal: 20.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Image.asset('images/login.jpg'),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email:',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      errorStyle:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                    ),
                    controller: emailController,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please Enter Email';
                      } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Please Enter Valid Email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    errorStyle:
                        TextStyle(color: Colors.black26, fontSize: 15.0),
                  ),
                  controller: passwordController,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please Enter Password';
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          setState(() {
                            email = emailController.text;
                            password = passwordController.text;
                          });
                          userLogin();
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Login',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ForgotPass(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Forget Password ?',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const Text('Do Not Have Account ?'),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            PageRouteBuilder(
                              pageBuilder: (context, a, b) => Signup(),
                              transitionDuration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
                            ),
                            (route) => false);
                      },
                      child: const Text('Signup'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Iused these packages

```
firebase_core: ^1.5.0
firebase_auth: ^3.0.2
```

I searched a lot and found a lot of codes and This code is the best I've found

please i need help quickly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add (keep the auth like it is) cloud firestore and set a doc for each user contains his name , last name , job , profile pic etc...

so every user will have doc on cloud firestore and user on Auth

some sources :

to set the user in singUp page :

https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/